# How to Drop rows from pandas dataframe by using a list of indices

Tags: python, pandas

## Introduction

We have the following dataframe which we create from a CSV file.

`data = pd.read_csv(path + name, usecols = ['QTS','DSTP','RSTP','DDATE','RDATE','DTIME','RTIME','DCXR','RCXR','FARE']`)

I want to delete specific rows from the dataframe. For this purpose I used a list and appended the ids of the rows we want to delete.

```
for index,row in data.iterrows():
     if (row['FARE'] >= 2500.00):
       indices.append(index)
```

**From here i am lost. Don't know how to use the ids in the list to delete the rows from the dataframe**

---

## Question

- The list containing the row ids must be used in the dataframe to delete rows. Is it possible to do it?

---

## Constraints

- We can't use `data.drop(index,inplace=True)` because it really slows the process
- We **cannot** use a **filter** because I have some special constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to remove rows that have `'FARE'` values greater than or equal to zero, you can use a mask that have those values lesser than `2500` -

```
df_out = df.loc[df.FARE.values < 2500] # Or df[df.FARE.values < 2500]
```

For large datasets, we might want to work with underlying array data and then construct the output dataframe -

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df.values[df.FARE.values < 2500], columns=df.columns)
```

---

To use those `indices` generated from the loopy code in the question -

```
df_out = df.loc[np.setdiff1d(df.index, indices)]
```

Or with `masking` again -

```
df_out = df.loc[~df.index.isin(indices)]  # or df[~df.index.isin(indices)]
```

Comment: thank you @Divakar but is there a way to use the ids as i stated in the question?

Comment: @HaniGotc By ids, do you mean `indices` from the loop?

Comment: by using the list **indices** which contains the indices of the rows to delete

Answer (score 0):

How about filtering data using [DataFrame.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
cols = ['QTS','DSTP','RSTP','DDATE','RDATE','DTIME','RTIME','DCXR','RCXR','FARE']
df = pd.read_csv(path + name, usecols=cols).query("FARE < 2500")
```